# HTTP Callout Test Error

Tags: apex, unit-test, apexrest, compile-error, httpcalloutmock

I'm trying to push some code from one of our sandboxes to production.

Class:

```
public class CloudtoDevOps {    
    @future (callout=true)
    public static void sendNotification(String ClientID, String Name, String Status, String Datacenter, Decimal Users, Decimal Storage) {

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('client_id', ClientID);
        gen.writeStringField('client_full_name', Name);
        gen.writeStringField('status', Status);
        gen.writeStringField('hosted_datacenter', Datacenter);
        gen.writeNumberField('number_of_licenses', Users);
        gen.writeNumberField('storage_amount_in_gb', Storage);
        gen.writeEndObject();

        String jsonString = gen.getAsString();

        req.setEndpoint('URL');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        req.setBody(jsonString);

        try {
            res = http.send(req);
        } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
            System.debug(res.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger CloudtoDev on Cloud_Environment__c (after insert, after update) {
    for (Cloud_Environment__c c: Trigger.new) {
        CloudtoDevOps.SendNotification(c.Client_ID__c, c.Name, c.Status__c, c.Data_Center__c, c.Users__c, c.Storage_Amount__c);
    }
}
```

Mock Callout:

```
@isTest
global class CloudtoDevOpsMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        System.assertEquals('URL', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);

        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeStringField('client_id', 'abcabc');
        gen.writeStringField('client_full_name', 'Test Account');
        gen.writeStringField('status', 'Live');
        gen.writeStringField('hosted_datacenter', 'CH3');
        gen.writeNumberField('number_of_licenses', 100);
        gen.writeNumberField('storage_amount_in_gb', 200);
        gen.writeEndObject();
        String jsonString = gen.getAsString();

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        res.setBody(jsonString);
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class CloudtoDevOpsTest {
    @isTest public static void testCallout() {
        System.test.setMock(System.HttpCalloutMock.class, new CloudtoDevOpsMock());
        HttpResponse response = CloudtoDevOps.sendNotification('abcab', 'Test Account', 'Live', 'CH3', 100, 200);
        String contentType = response.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
        String actualResultValue = response.getBody();
        String expectedResultValue = '{"client_id": "abcab","client_full_name": "Test Account","status": "Live","hosted_datacenter": "CH3","number_of_licenses": 100,  "storage_amount_in_gb": 200}';
        System.assertEquals(actualResultValue, expectedResultValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCode());
        System.debug(actualResultValue);
        System.debug(expectedResultValue);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error on line 5 of the test class: Illegal assignment from void to System.HttpResponse

I've test the class/trigger using requestb.in and everything works as I would expect but I can't push to production because code coverage is coming back as 0%.

Answer (score 1):

Your method doesn't return any value, since its return type is `void`. So you cannot make any direct assertions on your `HttpResponse`. It wouldn't make sense to do so anyway, since the response is mocked. What you need to test is how your code handles a given response. Or in this case, since you don't do any processing of the response, just check that a callout is consumed.

```
Test.startTest();
    // call method
    Integer callouts = Limits.getCallouts();
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(1, callouts, 'The method should make a callout');
```

If you want to make assertions about what headers you set on your *request*, you could certainly cache those in your mock.

```
@IsTest
public class MyMock
{
    static Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();

    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request)
    {
        headers.clear();
        headers.put('Content-Type', request.getHeader('Content-Type'));
        // etc.
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you could assert on which headers were included with the most recent request:

```
Test.startTest();
    // call method
    Integer callouts = Limits.getCallouts();
Test.stopTest();

system.assertEquals(1, callouts, 'The method should make a callout');
system.assertEquals(expectedContentType, MyMock.headers.get('Content-Type'),
    'The Content-Type header should be set');
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling is defined to have no return value (the `void`):

```
public static void sendNotification(...
```

so it is appropriate that this (that is assigning a return value):

```
HttpResponse response = CloudtoDevOps.sendNotification(...
```

won't compile.

Try "Compile all Classes" on the "Apex Classes" Setup page in the sandbox; I assume this won't compile there either and needs fixing in the sandbox first.